# Centering content & images in Mobile view (CSS)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been working on this for over an hour so hoping someone can help me figure this out!

I'm trying to get these images centered within mobile view, however, can't seem to get it work. [image]

I've tried a variety of custom css, however, I'm stuck...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
.fusion-column-wrapper {
padding-left: 25px !important;
}}
```

Here's the page I'm trying to figure it out on.
http://blisspaperboutique.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the wrapping anchor tag and img both to `display: block`. Also, set `margin: 0 auto` on the img.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
  .fusion-column-wrapper a {
    display: block;
  }
  .fusion-column-wrapper a img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried on Chrome and Firefox with the added rules and both are centering the images for me. Mind creating a fiddle? I've also updated my answer with a screenshot.

Comment: Hello — thank you for your help. I've inserted the code you suggested as well — you can see here that it has adjusted: http://blisspaperboutique.com/  Also, not sure what fiddle is? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Essentially everything below "Some of our FAVORITE templates" I need to have padding on the left like the rest of the page. Not sure what's going on here....

Comment: You don't need padding on the left, in fact that's not a recommended solution because of dynamic screen sizes. When I inspect your website, I'm not seeing the added code. I see you're familiar with the CSS Inspector panel, can you verify the code above has been added to your published site?

Comment: I do not see it in there either when using the inspector — I am adding the code under "Advanced CSS Customizations" — using the avada theme. That's where I had added all my custom CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the method you are adding CSS to your site. It could be an issue with the media query setup? Try removing the code from the media query and placing it into the normal CSS (outside of the media query). It shouldn't affect the layout on full desktop size.